# Rails console: NoMethodError: undefined method `attributes_builder' for #<Array:0x007fd7af09f8b0>

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When I attempt to look up a record for one of my data models using the rails console by entering the following command:

UserOption.find(2)

I get the following error:
NoMethodError: undefined method `attributes_builder' for #

I added data to the user_options table in my Postgres db by using sql insert commands and not via the rails console or a rails script.  If I add data to the table using the rails console instead it will work fine.  Why should it matter if I add the data via rails vs. through sql commands on my database directly?

Thanks,
Angela

Answer (score 1):

I figured out my issue.  I had an attribute in my model which was named "type" which was causing the issue.  It has nothing to due with how the data was populated.